# LightSwitch: how to access and change control properties in AddAndEditNew default modal

Tags: c#, silverlight, modal-dialog, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

In LightSwitch, when I open the default modal, calling the AddAndEditNew_Execute method, I want to change properties of the controls inside the modal dialog.

For instance: I want to change a TextBox to "Multiline" or change AutoComplete FilterMode to "Contains".

How can I access to those controls in execution time?

I know I can add a custom modal, but I just want to change a small thing of it and I don't want to create a whole modal dialog just for this.

I'm always talking about Silverlight client.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that the only way you can do what you want is:

- with a *custom modal window* (if you want the window to be modal)
- or a *separate screen* (if you don't need the window to be modal)

The properties of a *default modal window* **can't** be changed. There are no mechanisms to change the properties of any of the controls.

The only thing that you can do is to **influence** which properties get displayed in the default modal window, by checking/unchecking the *Display By Default* check-box in the table designer.

But as soon as you need to make changes to either the layout of the controls, or changing any control's properties, you need to create a **custom modal window**, or **separate screen**, & display then by calling them in custom code.

The reason for this is because the controls for the *default modal window* are **generated** by the LightSwitch run-time.

It's really just a matter of a balance between *not having to do the work to create the window*, & *flexibility*.

**Default:**    Easy = Yes, Flexible = No
**Custom:**     Easy = No,  Flexible = Yes

I know it's not what you wanted to hear, but hopefully my explanation helps you to understand why you can't do it the way you first wanted to.

Comment: what if, just a wild thought, you were to make another table and fill that one in such a way that it is Autocomplete cell, and than add an relationship? is that possible? As of the moment i am trying this and i hope it'll work